# Azure Blob Trigger - Dynamic BlobOutput Binding Name Based on Input Container

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-blob-trigger

```
        [Function("Function1")]
        [BlobOutput("test-samples-output/{name}", Connection = "ConnectionString1")]

        public string Run([BlobTrigger("test-samples-trigger/{name}", Connection = "ConnectionString1")] string myBlob,
            string name, string blobTrigger)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name: {name} \n Data: {myBlob}");
            
            return myBlob;
        }
```

I have a blob trigger set to 'test-samples-trigger/{name}'. I want to set the BlobOutput to use the input container name '{input-container-name}-output/{name}'. Is there a way to set the BlobOuput string to dynamically point to this location?

Answer (score 1):

After reproducing from my end, One way to achieve your requirement is to read variable using `GetEnvironmentVariable` where the value is read from `local.settings.json`. Below is the complete code that worked for me.

Function1.cs

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp13
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([BlobTrigger("samples-workitems/{name}", Connection = "connstr")]Stream myBlob,
            [Blob("%outputContainer%/{name}", FileAccess.Write, Connection = "connstr")] Stream outputBlob, 
            string name, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name} \n Size: {myBlob.Length} Bytes");

            string outputContainer = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("outputContainer");

            outputBlob.Write();
        }
    }
}
```

local.settings.json

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<ConnectionString>",
    "connstr": "<ConnectionString>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "outputContainer": "sample"
  }
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this would work for a single output location, but I was hoping to dynamically create it based on the input. For example, two triggers "samples-workitems1" and "samples-workitems2" could dynamically point to the outputs "samples-workitems1-output" and "samples-workitems2-output" respectively.

Comment: @CDWatson AFAIK, to achieve your requirement you can create multiple functions in your function app.

Comment: That is what I currently have. Each function has a custom output object with the correct output bindings for that function. Across 10+ functions this looks quite clumsy having this for each one so was wondering if a solution was possible to only have one of these objects with a relative path.

Comment: @CDWatson If Azure functions is not a must thing, then you can use logic apps in this case.

Answer (score 0):

local.setting.json

```
{
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "YOUR_AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING",
        "ContainerName": "mycontainer"  // Default container name
      }
    }

using System.Configuration;

public static void ProcessBlob(
    [BlobTrigger("%ContainerName%/{name}", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] Stream myBlob,
    string name)
{
    // Your code here
}
```